# How to Creating Submenus with SWRevealViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, menu

Hello Can any one tell how to achieve this
I am able to achieve the slide in and out but not able to create a sub menu for more information plz click the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800465/creating-submenus-with-swrevealviewcontroller-swift